# How to send a localized email

Tags: c#, localization

I want to send user a localized email, but it seems the text retrieved from resource file are based on my culture.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "password");
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.Sender = new MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com");
mm.From = new MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com");
mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
mm.Subject = Localization.EmailUserActiveTitle;
mm.Body = "<div><h3>" + Localization.EmailUserActiveBodyPart1 + "</h3></div></br>" +
            "<div>" + Localization.EmailUserActiveBodyPart2 + "</div>" +
            "<div><b>" + content + "</b></div></br>" +
            "<div>" + Localization.EmailUserActiveBodyPart3 + "</div>" +
            "<div>" + Localization.EmailUserActiveBodyPart4 + "</div>";
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
client.Send(mm);
```

But when i retrieve `Localization.EmailUserActiveBodyPart1` it is localized base on my current culture.

how can i retrieve specified culture resource file?

Comment: Check out setting the [CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx#Y456).

Comment: @Filburt I know this approach, but it seems to change My culture instead of retrieve corresponding culture resource text.

Comment: You didn't mention it in your question so I want to give a hint. See Clafou's detailed answer how to handle this in your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ResourceManager uses the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture property to determine which localized language version of a resource to load.

So if you want to force localization to a specific language (e.g. the language preference associated with the user you are sending email to), then just do this before your code:

```
var previousUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); // Replace with the relevant culture name for your user
```

And clean up* just after your code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = previousUICulture;
```

*Obviously this is not a reliable clean-up. A `finally` block or wrapping this language-switching functionality in an `IDisposable` and using a `using` block would prevent your code running in a random language in case of a failure, but that's outside the point.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to specify the culture and retrieve it without set my own culture.

Comment: It depends on your requirement for deciding which language to use when you send an email. Assuming the language depend on the user, how do you determine which language to use for a given user?